# api for indexed variadic arguments

Tags: c++, c++17, compiler-optimization, variadic-functions, template-meta-programming

I don't know if there is a good and clean way to index variadic arguments when unpacking tuple-like objects into callable handlers, i.e. when using `std::apply`.

Here is a not perfect, but rather clean solution:

```
    const auto animals = std::make_tuple("cow", "dog", "sheep");

    // handwritten, stateful, bad...
    std::apply([](const auto& ... str){
        const auto print = [](const auto& str, size_t index){
            std::cout << index << ": " << str << '\n';
        };

        // this should not be done by the user!!!
        size_t i = 0;
        (print(str, i++), ...);
    }, animals);
```

This solution is cleaner than using overloads with `std::index_sequence` since you don't have to write any code outside lambda's scope. **Templates are not allowed within a block scope**, so one would need to create some helper class outside.
**It is bad**, since there is a mutable state that is created by user. There should be no such thing, index should be available **implicitly** and **on demand**.

Here is what I think is desired and what I managed to implement so far:

```
    const auto animals = std::make_tuple("cow", "dog", "sheep");

    // desired
    // JavaScript-style destructuring. 
    // C++ structured bindings are not allowed as arguments
    // apply([](auto ... {value, index}){ ... }, animals);

    // still bad, but better - index is implicit and constant
    std::apply(indexed([](auto ... indexedValue){
        const auto print = [](const auto& indexedValue){
            const auto &[index, value] = indexedValue;
            std::cout << index << ": " << value << '\n';
        };
        (print(indexedValue), ...);
    }), animals);
```

C++ does not allow to have structured bindings as function arguments, and this is **very unfortunate**. Anyways, I consider this api better, than incrementing a counter by hand or writing some boilerplate helper.
All you have to do is to <strike>follow the damn train</strike> wrap your callable into `indexed()` function.
And it does not require any modifications on STL's part.

However, my implementation is very far from optimal. It results in far more instructions than the first example: https://godbolt.org/z/3G4doao39

Here is my implementation for `indexed()` function which I would like to be corrected.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

namespace detail {
    template <size_t I, typename T>
    struct _indexed
    {
        constexpr static size_t index = I;
        T value;

        constexpr _indexed(std::integral_constant<size_t, I>, T t)
            : value(t)
        {}

        template <size_t Elem>
        friend constexpr auto get(const detail::_indexed<I, T>& v) noexcept -> 
                std::tuple_element_t<Elem, detail::_indexed<I, T>>{
            if constexpr (Elem == 0)
                return I;
            if constexpr (Elem == 1)
                return v.value;
        }

    };

    template <size_t I, typename T>
    _indexed(std::integral_constant<size_t, I>, T) -> _indexed<I, T>;

    template <typename CRTP>
    class _add_indices
    {
    public:
        template <typename ... Args>
        constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(Args &&... args) const noexcept {
            return (*this)(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    private:
        template <typename ... Args, size_t ... I>
        constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(std::index_sequence<I...>, Args ... args) const noexcept {
            // does not compile 
            // return std::invoke(&CRTP::callable, static_cast<CRTP const&>(*this), 
            //     _indexed(std::integral_constant<size_t, I>{}, std::forward<Args>(args))...);
            return static_cast<const CRTP&>(*this).callable(_indexed(std::integral_constant<size_t, I>{}, std::forward<Args>(args))...);
        }
    };
}

template <size_t I, typename T>
struct std::tuple_size<detail::_indexed<I, T>> : std::integral_constant<size_t, 2> {};

template <size_t I, typename T>
struct std::tuple_element<0, detail::_indexed<I, T>>
{
    using type = size_t;
};

template <size_t I, typename T>
struct std::tuple_element<1, detail::_indexed<I, T>>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename Callable>
constexpr auto indexed(Callable c) noexcept{
    struct _c : detail::_add_indices<_c> {
        Callable callable;
    };

    return _c{.callable = c};
}

// api:
// apply(indexed([](auto ... indexedValue){}), tuple);
```

Comment: Not sure what you want, but `[&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        ((std::cout << Is << ": " << std::get<Is>(animals) << '\n'), ...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(animals)>>());` does your output [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PYvoz6YMf)

Comment: @Jarod42 it does. But it is ugly AF. I want an api which is clean and simple to use. Its implementation may create as many `std::Index_sequence`s as needed, but the user should be able to just access the index on demand. `const auto &[value, index]` is the most desirable

Comment: @Jarod42 also it is for C++20. The tag here is C++17 (despite using designated initializers, yeah)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand what do you want... it seems to me that you only need a class/struct as follows

```
template <typename Callable>
struct indexed_call
{
  Callable c;

  template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... As>
  constexpr auto call (std::index_sequence<Is...>, As && ... as) const {
    return c(std::pair{Is, std::forward<As>(as)}...);
  }

  template <typename ... As>
  constexpr auto operator() (As && ... as) const {
    return call(std::index_sequence_for<As...>{}, std::forward<As>(as)...);
  }
};
```

and an explicit, trivial, deduction guide

```
template <typename C>
indexed_call(C) -> indexed_call<C>;
```

and the call change a little as follows

```
std::apply(indexed_call{[](auto ... indexedValue){
   const auto print = [](const auto& iV){
      const auto &[index, value] = iV;
      std::cout << index << ": " << value << '\n';
   };
   (print(indexedValue), ...);
}}, animals);
```

or, if you prefer, also the call can be simplified

```
std::apply(indexed_call{[](auto ... iV){
   ((std::cout << iV.first << ": " << iV.second << '\n'), ...);
}}, animals);
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename Callable>
struct indexed_call
{
  Callable c;

  template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... As>
  constexpr auto call (std::index_sequence<Is...>, As && ... as) const {
    return c(std::pair{Is, std::forward<As>(as)}...);
  }

  template <typename ... As>
  constexpr auto operator() (As && ... as) const {
    return call(std::index_sequence_for<As...>{}, std::forward<As>(as)...);
  }
};

template <typename C>
indexed_call(C) -> indexed_call<C>;

int main(){
    const auto animals = std::make_tuple("cow", "dog", "sheep");

    std::apply(indexed_call{[](auto ... indexedValue){
       const auto print = [](const auto& iV){
          const auto &[index, value] = iV;
          std::cout << index << ": " << value << '\n';
       };
       (print(indexedValue), ...);
    }}, animals);

    std::apply(indexed_call{[](auto ... iV){
       ((std::cout << iV.first << ": " << iV.second << '\n'), ...);
    }}, animals);
}
```

----- EDIT -----

The OP writes

> I don't think that utilizing std::pair is semantically correct. Would be better to have .value, .index

I usually prefer to use standard components, when functional equivalents, but if you want something with a `value` and a `index` components, you can add a simple struct (name it as you prefer)

```
template <typename V>
struct val_with_index
{
  std::size_t  index;
  V            value;
};
```

and another trivial explicit deduction guide

```
template <typename V>
val_with_index(std::size_t, V) -> val_with_index<V>;
```

then you have to modify the `call()` method to use it instead `std::pair`

```
template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... As>
constexpr auto call (std::index_sequence<Is...>, As && ... as) const {
  return c(val_with_index{Is, std::forward<As>(as)}...);
} // ......^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and now works for the double lambda case

For the simplified case, obviously you have to change `first` and `second` with `index` and `value`

```
std::apply(indexed_call{[](auto ... iV){
   ((std::cout << iV.index << ": " << iV.value << '\n'), ...);
}}, animals); // ....^^^^^...............^^^^^
```

Again the full compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename V>
struct val_with_index
{
  std::size_t  index;
  V            value;
};

template <typename V>
val_with_index(std::size_t, V) -> val_with_index<V>;

template <typename Callable>
struct indexed_call
{
  Callable c;

  template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... As>
  constexpr auto call (std::index_sequence<Is...>, As && ... as) const {
    return c(val_with_index{Is, std::forward<As>(as)}...);
  }

  template <typename ... As>
  constexpr auto operator() (As && ... as) const {
    return call(std::index_sequence_for<As...>{}, std::forward<As>(as)...);
  }
};

template <typename C>
indexed_call(C) -> indexed_call<C>;

int main(){
    const auto animals = std::make_tuple("cow", "dog", "sheep");

    std::apply(indexed_call{[](auto ... indexedValue){
       const auto print = [](const auto& iV){
          const auto &[index, value] = iV;
          std::cout << index << ": " << value << '\n';
       };
       (print(indexedValue), ...);
    }}, animals);

    std::apply(indexed_call{[](auto ... iV){
       ((std::cout << iV.index << ": " << iV.value << '\n'), ...);
    }}, animals);
}
```

Comment: this is nice, but I don't think that utilizing `std::pair` is semantically correct. Would be better to have `.value, .index`. And since `.index` is known at compile time, I think it is better to have it as a non-template argument.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik - Answer modified.

Comment: Nice. Can it be modified to be used within `std::for_each` and other operations on ranges, when user is expected to provide an UnaryFunction?

Comment: also within your struct you can have `constexpr static size_t index = I;` It is known at compile time

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik- For the `for_each` question... well I don't know... I mean... I don't know what do you exactly want; maybe you should write in in another answer. For the `constexpr static` `index`... yes, if you want. But become more complex. See you if it's preferable.

Comment: What I want is a simpler api that is easy to use. Getting indexes or keys of iterable objects is a no-brainer in dynamicly typed languages like JavaScript or Python. Using `indexed_call` as a wrapper provides that functionality while being easy to comprehend. While It is not as good as in a dynamic language, I suppose it is the best one can get for the time being.